# PDF Print class generates corrupted PDF from WebView on some devices

Tags: android, pdf, webview

My Android application receives a Base64 string from server and load that base64 into the WebView. I am trying to convert that WebView content to a PDF file, save PDF file to the phone and start an intent to send the generated PDF. The problem is on some devices(especially Samsungs with Android 13 and Huawei devices), when users send the generated PDF on whatsapp and try to open it, the phone says "corrupted PDF" and don't let users to open the PDF file. Additionally there is no problem with displaying content in WebView on all devices. I am using below class to convert webView to PDF:

```
import android.os.CancellationSignal;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;

public class PdfPrint {
    private static final String TAG = PdfPrint.class.getSimpleName();
    private final PrintAttributes printAttributes;

    public PdfPrint(PrintAttributes printAttributes) {
        this.printAttributes = printAttributes;
    }

    public void print(final PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter, final File path, final String fileName, final CallbackPrint callback) {
        printAdapter.onLayout(null, printAttributes, null, new PrintDocumentAdapter.LayoutResultCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutFinished(PrintDocumentInfo info, boolean changed) {
                printAdapter.onWrite(new PageRange[]{PageRange.ALL_PAGES}, getOutputFile(path, fileName), new CancellationSignal(), new PrintDocumentAdapter.WriteResultCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onWriteFinished(PageRange[] pages) {
                        super.onWriteFinished(pages);
                        if (pages.length > 0) {
                            File file = new File(path, fileName);
                            String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
                            callback.success(path);
                        } else {
                            callback.onFailure("Pages length not found");
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        }, null);
    }

    private ParcelFileDescriptor getOutputFile(File path, String fileName) {
        if (!path.exists()) {
            path.mkdirs();
        }
        File file = new File(path, fileName);
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_WRITE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to open ParcelFileDescriptor", e);
        }
        return null;
    }


    public interface CallbackPrint {
        void success(String path);

        void onFailure(String errorMsg);
    }
}
```

The most difficult obstacle to solve this problem is, this problem not happening all devices all the time. Sometimes same device can generate a correct PDF from same Webview while sometime later device can't generate a correct PDF from same WebView. And sometimes removing and re-installing the app could solve the problem. I don't know where to look for, can anyone help?

Comment: `and load that base64 into the WebView. ` Hmmm... what do you see if a WebView displays a base64 string? And what was encoded in that string?

Comment: @blackapps actually my base64 is an encoded HTML. I am loading the base64 into the WebView like following: `loadData(base64str!!, MIME_TYPE, ENCODING)` **MIME_TYPE = "text/html"** and **ENCODING = "base64"** When i am loading i see the HTML page that i want to convert to PDF

Comment: Thank you. I didnt know that such construct was possible.

Comment: Can you show how you call your print class from webview?

Comment: If you want to achieve an accurate standard on every platform. You need to receive the data as PDF instead of Base 64.

Comment: @ΓDΛ do you mean don't use HTML to generate a PDF but get PDF directly from server ?

Comment: Now you both are talking partly nonsense. It was suggested to get the html source from server. Not base64 encoded.

Comment: Or let the app decode the base64 first and then feed the html to the webview.

Comment: So find out if this has to do with base64 encoding. Why not directly load a html page?

Comment: @blackapps actually there are two webViews. one for users to see and the other for generating a PDF. i have two separate webViews because when i read the createPrintDocumentAdapter documentation it says: _"The WebView cannot be drawn during the conversion process - any such draws are undefined. It is recommended to use a dedicated off screen WebView for the printing. If necessary, an application may temporarily hide a visible WebView by using a custom PrintDocumentAdapter instance."_ And in the second webview(generates a PDF) i am decoding the base64 and load the HTML string actually.

Comment: You should feed the webview that generates the pdf with html. Not with base64 was the hint.

Comment: Actually thats what i am trying to say. I am already feeding the webView that generates the pdf with the HTML I am decoding the base64 to HTML before i load the webView that generates the pdf. I am only feed the webview that users seeing with the base64

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255637/discussion-between-tolgahan-tutar-and-blackapps).